# jquery select year from previous till 1900

Tags: jquery, date, select

This gotta be simple but I'm stuck...

I wanna make my current year select to behave so that default selected year is previous year from today. So if today is 2013, the most higher year you could select is 2012 and the lowest is 1900.

In my jsfiddle I have situation where the highest available selected year is 2013, but default value is 2012, I'm stuck and I don't know further: http://jsfiddle.net/vqJfn/

html:

```
<select class="date-input register_input" name="date_from_statement" id="date_from_statement">
<option value="0">2012</option>
</select>
```

js:

```
 $(function(){
    for (i = new Date().getFullYear(); i > 1900; i--)
    {
    $('#date_from_statement').append($('<option/>').val(i).html(i));
    }
 });
```

I know that this is simple but I'm beginner so don't judge me please... help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean

```
("#date_from_statement").val(new Date().getFullYear()-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    for (i = new Date().getFullYear() -1; i > 1900; i--) {
        $('#date_from_statement').append($('<option/>').val(i).html(i));
    }
});
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/vqJfn/1/

Answer (score 1):

There was  a simple mistake i have corrected it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/vqJfn/3/)

I have commented out the option tag

```
<select class="date-input register_input" name="date_from_statement" id="date_from_statement">
   <!--<option value="0"></option>-->
</select>
```

**JS Code:** Modifed your for cond as well

```
$(function () {
 for (i = new Date().getFullYear() -1; i > 1900; i--) {
      $('#date_from_statement').append($('<option/>').val(i).html(i));
 }
});
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `option` from the HTML and use the following jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    var currYear = new Date().getFullYear(),
        option,
        i;
    for (i = 1900; i < currYear; i += 1) {
        option = $(document.createElement('option')).val(i).text(i);
        option.prop('selected', i === currYear - 1);
        $('#date_from_statement').append(option);
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JhXbE/2/)